# Selenium sendKeys to a password input box is not accepted by the browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

[image]

Try some selenium web automation. sendKeys("123456") to password input box, fill the smsCode. then click the submit button. It gives the error tips "bankcard passwords must be 6 numbers, please fill it again." I have try this three kinds of sending ways, but it gives the same error tips:

```
var passwordField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('_ocx_password'))
passwordField.click()

passwordField.sendKeys(["123456"])

passwordField.sendKeys("123456")

passwordField.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.NUMPAD1)
passwordField.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.NUMPAD2)
passwordField.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.NUMPAD3)
passwordField.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.NUMPAD4)
passwordField.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.NUMPAD5)
passwordField.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.NUMPAD6)
```

Could someone tell me how to deal with it and submit successfully? Many thanks.

More information about the question, I give out the element structure of   passwords input box and the submit button below:

```
<div id="debitCard_password">
<input type="text" onfocus="this.type='password';pgeCtrl.openProt('password1530252XX13701',this.id);pgeCtrl.setCX(this);" onkeydown="pgeCtrl.setSX(event,'',this);" onclick="pgeCtrl.setCX(this)" onblur="pgeCtrl.closeProt('password15302529613701',this.id)" id="_ocx_password" style="ime-mode:disabled" tabindex="2" class="ocx_atm" value=""></div>

<p style="padding-top:0px">
                                <input id="btnCardPay" name="btnCardPay" type="button" value="开通并付款" class="btn_blue139p CardDefault">
                            </p >
```

I can't reproduce the scenes by manual input.

--------------------------------something new------------------------------

[image]

When I manual enter the passwords, I find that it detects the number of words I have typed.

[image]

And the auto typing it is too short to detect the number of words.
[image]

Then I put a line after sendKeys : java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000). But the words disappeared when the sleep start, so the number of words having typed is 0.

I want to use another sending method.

```
var passwordField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('_ocx_password'))
var actions = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(WDS.browser)
actions.keyDown(passwordField, "123456")
actions.pause(1000);
```

It throws errors like this:

TypeError: Can not invoke method [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.OverloadedDynamicMethod
 Actions org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.keyDown(Keys)
 Actions org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.keyDown(WebElement,Keys)

```
var errorMsg = new java.lang.String()
var e = new java.awt.AWTException(errorMsg)
try {
    var robot = new java.awt.Robot()

    var loc = new org.openqa.selenium.Poin()
    loc = passwordField.getLocation();
    WDS.log.info(loc.getX()+2, loc.getY()+2)

    // Simulate a key press
    robot.mouseMove(loc.getX()+2, loc.getY()+2);
    robot.mousePress(java.awt.event.InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_3);
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_5);
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_2);
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_4);
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_6);
    robot.delay(10000);
    robot.mouseRelease(java.awt.event.InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    } catch (e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        WDS.log.info(e)
}
```

It throws error like this :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Poin.

So I wonder what is the key in solving this problem.

Comment: Try sending it one character at a time with a short time gap in between.

Comment: @Belinda Xu  What version of Chrome and driver do you use?

Comment: @Grasshopper I let the sleep after typing the words, but the words in input box  disappeared when java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000) starts.

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov ChromeDriver 2.40, Chrome 67.0.3396.87

Comment: @BelindaXu Upgrade y ChromeDriver to latest 2.48, and will work fine.